# composer self-update error when deploying on a shared hosting server

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I am attempting to deploy app on a live server. I copied the git repo to the new location and ran composer self-update and received the following error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
Filesystem exception:
Composer update failed: the "/usr/local/bin/composer.phar" file could not be written
```

How can I update composer?

Comment: seems a permission problem. have you given the writing permission on the `/usr/local/bin/` folder?

Comment: I just did a chmod -R 755 bin and I ran the composer update again and received the same error

Comment: Did you use the magic fix-everything prefix `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

It will be tough to deploy with Composer on shared hosting because you have limited permissions and resources. Try to use VPS - cheap ones like DigitalOcean are almost the same price with shared hosting.

If you really need to use shared hosting it's better to deploy locally and then upload ready files to remote server. Don't forget to clear the cache and update permissions to cache and logs folder.